# Conditional code generation using StringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate

In my project, I have a class `Device` like this:

```
public class Device {
    private Set<String> abilities = new HashSet<String>();

    public Device(Set<String> abilities) {
        this.abilities = abilities;
    }

    public Set<String> getAbilities() {
        return abilities;
    }
}
```

I am initializing this `Device` class with:

```
Set<String> device1Abilities = new HashSet<String>();
device1Abilities.add("BadgeReader"); 
device1Abilities.add("TemperatureSensor");   
device1Abilities.add("xyz");
Device d1 = new Device(device1Abilities);
```

In my `stringTemplateFile`, I am retrieving abilities using

```
$device.abilities :{ sc | abilities.add("$sc$"); }$
```

which will generates following code =>

```
abilities.add("BadgeReader");
abilities.add("TemperatureSensor");
abilities.add("xyz");
```

Now, my requirement is ----- I do not want to generate this line of code:

```
abilities.add("xyz");
```

What condition should I specify in

```
 $device.abilities :{ sc | abilities.add("$sc$"); }$
```

so that it does not generate that line?

Comment: What is the condition you'd like to test? That the argument is `"xyz"`?

Comment: My condition : if ( abilitity.equals("xyz") then do not print/generate , other wise in all case, all other line of code should be generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That computation really belongs in the model so you should do the filtering of the list that you passed to the template. The template should not figure out which data to display. It should display the data that your model says it should display. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Terence Parr, Before asking this question to stackoverflow community, I have asked the same question on stringTemplate.org.  thanks for your rocket speed reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Templates). You are using an anonymous sub-template `abilities.add("$sc$");`. Instead you can use a template call with sc as parameter. And there you can test on `"xyz"`. *Though maybe someone with more StringTemplate experience knows a shorter notation.*

Comment: Aye, and Terence Parr just answered.